# Communication between 2 channels

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hello Hyperledger community,

So I was testing some stuff with Hyperledger Fabric and I wondered if it's possible for 2 channels to share informations to some extent.

For example let's say we have 3 organisations Org1, Org2 and Org3.

Org1 and Org3 are resellers and Org2 is a shipper.

Org2 communicates with Org1 via Channel 2-1 and Org2 communicates with Org3 via Channel 2-3. But Org1 and Org3 can't communicate with each other since they don't share any businesses together.

But Org2 wants to keep all those informations on one and only ledger because it's way easier for it to handle it's data by looking through just one ledger than 2 different all the time.

So is there a way for Org2 to have a Channel just for itself, Channel 2 and create automatically transactions on it when Org2 receives or create transactions on Channel 2-1 and 2-3 ?

For example, let's say Org1 has made an order (id #A1598) of 20 cars through Channel 2-1 and Org3 has made an order (id #B502) of 2 tons of potatoes through Channel 2-3. Is there a way for Channel 2 to get automatically those data too ? So that the transaction is also written on it with all the references that could guide Org2 to check the transaction on Channel 2-1 if there is a problem one day.

And when Org2 would request Channel2 for all transactions there would be something like that:

```
[{
    id: 'A1598',
    channel: '2-1',
    org: 'Org1',
    details: '20 cars',
    price: 'xxxxx$'
},
{
    id: 'B502',
    channel: '2-3',
    org: 'Org3',
    details: '2 tons of potatoes',
    price: 'xxxxx$'
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically reacting on transactions being done in one channel and doing something in the other is a good use case for events.

ChainCode example:

```
eventPayload := "Order requested by Org1" + someOtherPayload
payloadAsBytes := []byte(eventPayload)
stub.SetEvent("Order requested", payloadAsBytes)
```

So projecting it to your example:

> For example, let's say Org1 has made an order (id #A1598) of 20 cars through Channel 2-1 and Org3 has made an order (id #B502) of 2 tons of potatoes through Channel 2-3. Is there a way for Channel 2 to get automatically those data too ?

When org1 (reseller) orders 20 cars it emits an event in the chaincode (e.g. above "order requested") on this event you can listen to with an org2 user from your backend who is enrolled member of this channel. When now org3 creates an order there is also an event emitted ("order requested"). Now the enrolled user of org2 who has also access to channel with org1 can ask on this channel whether the new transaction exceeds the limit of the day and can react accordingly.

See for example this Tutorial for [node](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-events.html). Or just search for the appropriate tutorial which serves your programming language.